$x_1,...,x_4$ are irreducible in $k[x_1,..,x_4]/\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3\rangle$
Let $k$ be a field (not sure whether there are conditions on characteristic and algebraic closure). I want to show that the classes of $x_1,...,x_4$ in $R:=k[x_1,..,x_4]/\langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3\rangle$ are irreducible but not prime. This is an exercise from Gathmann's notes on algebraic geometry. Let us look at, say $x_1$. Define $I := \langle x_1x_4-x_2x_3 \rangle$.
For the irreducibility assume $x_1 + I = pq + I$ where $p,q \in k[x_1,...]$ are non units. Then we have that there is a $g \in k[x_1,...]$ such that
$$pq - x_1 = g (x_1x_4 - x_2 x_3)$$
But now it is unclear how to proceed. I do not see how to conclude a contradiction. Perhaps one could look at
$$pq-g(x_1x_4 - x_2x_3) = x_1$$
Since $\text{deg } pq, \text{deg } g(x_1x_4-x_2x_3) \geq 2$ and their difference is of degree 1 we must have that the summands of degree $\geq 2$ have to be identical in $pq$ and $g(x_1x_4-x_2x_3)$. Also degree 1 summands can only occur in $pq$.

Are you familiar with homogeneous ideals? When you divide by a homogeneous ideal, the quotient ring is naturally graded, and so the elements of the quotient have degrees, just like polynomials. Moreover, if the homogeneous ideal is also prime (like here) then the degree satisfies the rule $\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$. So here, the cosets of $x_i$ are elements of degree $1$, which gives an easy explanation to them being irreducible.

I thought of that, too but was not fully aware of how exactly graded rings work. Thank you! Do you have a short sketch on why we need that the ideal is prime for the summability of degrees.

Same proof as of the fact that if $R$ is an integral domain then this identity holds for polynomials in $R[x]$ - in this case, the leading term of the product will just be the product of leading terms. If the quotient is not an integral domain then the product of leading terms might be $0$, and then the degree of the product will be smaller.

This looks like the coordinate ring of $2\times 2$ matrices with determinant $0$. Such matrices are of rank $1$, so can be written in a certain way, $x_1 = a b$, $x_4 = c d$, $x_2=a c$, $x_3 = b d$. So  now you can show that your ring is isomorphic to the subring $R$ of $k[a,b,c,d]$ generated by $a b$, $c d$, $a d$, $b c$. It is easier to work in this ring since it is a UFD. If you could factor inside $R$, then you could also factor in $k[a,b,c,d]$. However, $a b$ inside $k[a,b,c,d]$  factors uniquely (up to constants in $k$) as $a \cdot b$, and these factors are not in $R$.
